# Spring boot best approach for managing unhandled bookings

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, scheduled-tasks

I am in the process of developing a hotel booking system with a spring boot backend. Once a customer places a booking, the booking will be saved on the database with the status - "new" and there is an API endpoint available for the hotel's internal system to poll new bookings. Once the bookings are pulled, the hotel's system will mark the status of the booking as "confirmed" via the API.

All this is working fine, however now I need to implement a way for both the hotel and the admins to be notified if the hotel's system does not confirm the booking after a said time.

For example, if the unhandled notification time is set at 24 hours, then the system should automatically call the relevant webhooks if a booking's status is not accepted or rejected after 24 hours.

The initial approach I had is to have a method which runs in the background every hour and check all the bookings which are not accepted and call the appropriate webhooks. However, I am not entirely sure whether that is th best approach as there can be thousands of unhandled bookings at a given time.

So my question is, what would be the best approach to handle this and is there any way we can queue these booking unhandled checks so that for each booking, a method will be automatically called after 24 hours to check the status?

Comment: save the time of the request in your database, then every hour simply query for the `new identifier  + time range (24±1 hours)`. Check if the db you using allows for time range queries, this is more or less the simplest solution.

Comment: Will there be any issues if there are thousands of bookings which with a new identifier and past 24 hours?

Comment: that depends entirely on what your system can handle. Also if you really need to make thousands of notifications you need to make thousands of notifications, any workaround is purely project dependant. You could only return a projection of your data to limit memory usage, you could paginate the query results, there are a lot of solutions, but all of them depend on what is the desired end result.